# How to display choices in a django form based on a database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am writing a django application that helps create a shopping list based on the store stock.

The store stock will be stored as a database that looks like this (please ignore spelling errors!):

| Type | Name | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit | Apple | Pink |
| Fruit | Apple | Green |
| Fruit | Banana | Yellow |
| Fruit | Banana | Green |
| Fruit | Clementine | Orange |
| Fruit | Blueberry | Blue |
| Veg | Tomato | Red |
| Veg | Spinach | Dark green |
| Veg | Kale | Dark green |
| Veg | Dwarf beans | Light green |

From this store stock, a user can create a shopping list by choosing the above three fields using a form.

The user will first choose the type - which should be displayed as a choice between "Fruit" or "Veg".

Then when they choose "Fruit" for example, only the fruits should be provided as choices in "Name".

Finally, for them to choose colour, only the corresponding colour of the chosen fruit should be displayed as the options in the form.

To create the store stock database, the form I created is as follows:

```
Class Stock(models.Model):
    Type_choices = models.TextChoices('Fruit','Veg')
    stock_type = models.CharField(choices=Type_choices.choices)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=False)
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=False)
```

I then populated it to look like the above table.

To store the shopping list, I created a model:

```
Class ShoppingList(models.Model):
    stock_type = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    colour = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This model is definitely not correct and I was wondering if someone can please help me with this?

The form (in forms.py) for the shopping list is as follows:

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class ShoppingList(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ShoppingList
        fields = '__all__'
```

In the views.py file, I have the following:

```
def shopping_list_view(request):
    shopping_list_form = forms.ShoppingList()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        shopping_list_form = forms.ShoppingList()

        if shopping_list_form.is_valid():
            shopping_list_form.save(commit=True)

            return views.home_view(request)

    return render(request, 'shopping_list.html', {'form':shopping_list_form})
```

And finally, in the shopping_list.html file, I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ShoppingList</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Fill out shopping list</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="post">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="" id="" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Grateful if someone could please help me with this!

Comment: Can u show forms.ShoppingList?

Comment: u show model, i need form class @RC2210

Comment: If you want options, given options are available after selection by the user. You must use javascript or https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#creating-a-wizardview-subclass

Comment: Hi @kjaw - apologies I misread your comment. I have added the form to the question now (just below the models).